# Java unlimited relative mouse drag events

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt, mouse

Is there a way to offer the user unlimited relative mouse drag events in one of the Java GUI frameworks?

I would like to have a GUI element that the user can click and drag, but that element does not move: rather, some parameter (say color, volume, zoom level, etc.) gets adjusted in proportion to how far the user moves the mouse.

The trouble with Swing and SWT is that they want to report mouse *coordinates*, and those are bounded by the dimensions of the screen.  If the mouse pointer hits the edge of the screen during the drag operation, I'm afraid my GUI element will suddenly stop adjusting to further mouse movements by the user.

Is there a way to make this work in Java?

Comment: why don't you use JSlider?

Comment: Good question... I have very limited screen real estate.  I don't want the precision of the adjustment to be limited to the number of pixels I'm giving to the GUI element.  For example, if I want 256 possible levels of red in a color picker, I don't want to have to use up 256 pixels on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to look into the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, specifically [Robot#mouseMove(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove%28int,%20int%29).

You can listen for mouse drag events on the UI component which is being dragged via a `MouseMotionListener`, find the difference in the drag and reposition the mouse back onto the component.

This is a quick and dirty test to show that the idea works. **Note:** you will probably want to clean up the positioning of the mouse to stay at the same location; currently it just repositions the mouse to the centre of the `JLabel`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));

    final Robot r = new Robot();

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
    label.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    label.setOpaque(true);

    label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)    {}
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)    {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            Point point = label.getLocationOnScreen();
            point.x += (label.getWidth() / 2);
            point.y += (label.getHeight() / 2);
            r.mouseMove(point.x, point.y);

            Point movedPoint = e.getLocationOnScreen();

            int diffX = point.x - movedPoint.x;
            int diffY = point.y - movedPoint.y;
            System.out.println("Dragged: " + diffX + ", " + diffY);
        }
    });

    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty good answer.  I was only scared off by the part of the Robot documentation that says its constructor can throw AWTException "if the platform configuration does not allow low-level input control".

Comment: @Doradus: Any library capable of moving the mouse will at some point require low-level input control. That being said, if your program requires a mouse, you can be _fairly_ sure that you will have access.